# Make second image 50% smaller than first with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a wrapper and two images within displayed in a flexbox row. I would like to make sure, that the second image (on the right side) is 50% smaller than the first one (left side) and still strech te image on the whole space of 50%. So the left image is 50% bigger than the right. They both should use the whole width of the wrapper. How can I solve this?

Here is the example (red container = wrapper 1400px, left image 50% greater than right image, both image streching on whole wrapper and on their own container fit correctly):
[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container img-right">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: If R is 50% smaller than L, then L is 200% larger than R, not 50%

Comment: It's 2/3 to 1/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use flexbox, using `flex:1` in first `div` and `flex: 0 calc(100%/3)` in the second one

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.img-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block
}

.img-container:first-of-type {
  flex: 1
}

.img-container:last-of-type {
  flex: 0 calc(100%/3);
  /*for IE only*/
  flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x480/ccccccc">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x640/ccccccc">
  </div>
</div>
```

**OP's comment to above snippet:**

> Now its 2/3 to 1/3, this is perfekt. The only issue I have is, that my
>   right image doesn't look nice.. I think I have to center it and use
>   overflow: hidden; to make it look right? Ist this possible? I hope you
>   can imagine what I mean

you can then use `object-fit:cover`, note that it [doesn't work in IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.img-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-container:first-of-type {
  flex: 1
}

.img-container:last-of-type {
  flex: 0 calc(100%/3);
  /*for IE only*/
  flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually works, but the reasoning behind this formula is a bit unclear to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Changed the size of the intial images so they are now not the same size

Comment: @GolezTrol  yes I can elaborate, the premise is the second container has to be 50% smaller than the 1st one, so having 100%,  if I divide in 3 parts I'll have 3 equal parts, therefore `calc(100%/3)`,  which left me with 2/3 of the 3 equal parts which makes the double of the 1/3, and instead of using `flex: 0 66.7%` or `width: 66.7%`, let `flex-grow`do its job using `flex-grow: 1`  shorthandend `flex:1`

Comment: @Pete nowhere OP mentioned the images would be the same size ;)

Comment: Now its 2/3 to 1/3, this is perfekt. The only issue I have is, that my right image doesn't look nice.. I think I have to center it and use overflow: hidden;  to make it look right? Ist this possible? I hope you can imagine what I mean..

Comment: @MrBuggy see updated answer,  would be better to have a snippet with your actual images thought instead of imagining

Comment: @dippas object-fit: cover is nice but not supportet by IE: https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: @MrBuggy exactly what I said in my updated answer. you can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) for IE

Comment: @dippas I've got a solution without object-fit, I will upadte the answer later and mark this as correct because I used your soltuion for 2/3 to 1/3 layout

Comment: @dippas Do note, using `calc` with `flex` shorthand doesn't work on IE, it need the longhand `flex-basis` property ... also, since the `0` in your `flex: 0 calc(100%/3)` target the `flex-grow`, you can use the longhand _flex-basis_ alone.

Comment: @LGSon yup i'm aware of that, just updated the answer to take that into account, in regards to `also, since the 0 in your flex: 0 calc(100%/3) target the flex-grow, you can use the longhand flex-basis alone` you are right, I just like the shorthand version more ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use `width`s of 66.7% and 33.3% for the containers:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.img-container {
  display: inline-block
}

.img-container {
  width: 66.7%;
}

.img-container.img-right {
  width: 33.3%;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container img-right">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This way the left image is the double of the right one (it's 100% greater than right image).    
the width of `.img-container` should be 60% and 40% the one of  `.img-container.img-right`

Comment: @RubenDG Looks like OP clearly describes (and shows in the image) that the right image should be 50% of the left image, which is what you get when you divide the width in 2/3 and 1/3. It's what the other answers (try to) show as well. I think you misunderstood the question, maybe.

Comment: OP wrote once "that the second image (on the right side) is 50% smaller than the first one (left side)", then wrote two times "the left image is 50% bigger than the right". There is a conflict.     
  The first sentence means 66% and 33% (33 is the half of 66, so it's 50% smaller than the left image), the second one means 60% and 40%.    
Since OP wrote two times the second sentence, I thought that was the corrent one, Anyway the image provided in OP's example is 66% and 33%, so you're right.

Answer (score -1):

Try using flex-grow on the flex items (in your case img-container I guess).

```
.img-container {
    flex-grow: 2;
}

.img-container.img-right {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This page is a good guide for using flex:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This doesn't work in OP's snippet. The image aspect ratio seems to overrule this.